# How to use query datetimes with linq?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have database where I have `TimeStart` and `TimeEnd`, so I want to get only `StudentName` values that they are then days to finish. So each StudentName have `TimeStart` and `TimeEnd`

ViewModel:

```
    public List<SelectListItem> DurationDays { set; get; }
    public int SelectedDurationDays { set; get; }
```

Model:

```
 [Key]
    public int MyModelId { get; set; }
    public String StudentName { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime TimeStart{ get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime TimeEnd{ get; set; }
```

So as you can see, I do a SelectList Item to create a new TimeStart and TimeEnd, there is my logic:

Create Get:

```
  public async Task<ActionResult> Index(StudentsViewModel model)
    {
   var vm = new myViewModel
        {
            DurationDays = new List<SelectListItem>()

            {
                new SelectListItem {Value = "1", Text = "1 year"},
                new SelectListItem {Value = "2", Text = "2 years"},
            }}
```

Create Post

```
 var endDate = DateTime.Now.AddYears(model.SelectedDurationDays);
```

So my attempt to check the values ​​that are about to end is:

```
     var studentsEnd = db.MyModelList.Where(x => x.StudentName == model.StudentName)
            .Select(x => x.TimeEnd <= 10);
         if (studentsEnd <= 10)
        {
            //Alert logic
        }
```

What I'm doing wrong with my query? I only want to select StudentName that is near to TimeEnd

Comment: What exactly is the error or problem? Try displaying the value `x.TimeEnd` what do you get? How does that compare to `10`?

Comment: you can't compare `DateTime` and `int`

Comment: The problem is that I don't find the way to get the name of the student whose TimeEnd is ending , how can I make this query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your LINQ is wrong because you aren't doing any `where` clause using `DateTime`.

In your current LINQ, it could be translated to something like this in SQL:

```
SELECT (timeEnd <= 10) FROM MyModelList WHERE StudentName = ~variable~
```

You should've put the `DateTime` condition inside your `.Where()` clause too, like this:

```
 var studentsEnd = db.MyModelList.Where(x => x.StudentName == model.StudentName 
                   && x.TimeEnd <= otherDate);
```

Also, you're comparing a `DateTime` with a `int` value, it doesn't make any sense. You can only compare `DateTimes` with `DateTimes`.

If you're new to LINQ syntax querying a database, I do recommend you to use [`LINQPad`](https://www.linqpad.net/).

Comment: Oh damn, was going to answer the same.

Comment: Got it! Thanks for answer and suggestion

Comment: one question more, if I cant compare `DateTime` with `int`, how can I say to my query that my `TimeEnd` is going to finish, in example you give me you use `OtherDate`, but how can I  get this value, I look at function `DateTime.Now.Day <= 10` but I get error

Comment: What was `10` suppose to be? What is the condition of "`TimeEnd` is going to finish"? I didn't understand what condition you want achiev.

Comment: @CarlosM. your looking for DbFunctions class which will let you compare dates via entities and will properly translate to sql

Comment: And how can I use it for achieve that I want? @johnny5